# How to use select in laravel on left outer join as second criteria

Tags: mysql, laravel

I am trying to convert this mysql block to laravel sql but could not succeded in anyway

```
select tt.id
     , tt.date
     , m1.date
     , m2.date
     , m1.userid
     , m2.userid 
  from tbltickets tt 
  join tblticketreplies m1 
    on tt.id = m1.tid 
  left
  join tblticketreplies m2 
    on m1.tid = m2.tid 
   and m2.date =
     (SELECT min(m3.date) 
       FROM tblticketreplies m3 
      WHERE m3.date > m1.date 
        and m3.tid=m1.tid) 
 where tt.date > NOW() - INTERVAL 1 MONTH;
```

Laravel Block :

```
        $rows = DB::table('tbltickets')
        ->join('tblticketreplies as m1', 'tbltickets.id', '=', 'm1.tid')
        ->leftJoin("tblticketreplies as m2", function($join) {
            $join->on('m2.tid', '=', 'm1.tid');
            $join->on('m2.date',"=",DB::raw("SELECT min(m3.date) FROM tblticketreplies m3 WHERE m3.date > m1.date and m3.tid=m1.tid"));
        })
        ->select('tt.id as id,tt.date as first,m1.date as second,m2.date as third ,m1.userid as fid,m2.userid as sid')
        ->get();
```

does any body know how to use select in outer join or does it possible to do it ?

Answer (score 0):

You have not added alias to tbltickets (tt) and using it in select and secondly in select() you need to pass multiple arguments currently its just one long string.

```
<?php
 $rows = DB::table('tbltickets as tt')
        ->join('tblticketreplies as m1', 'tbltickets.id', '=', 'm1.tid')
        ->leftJoin("tblticketreplies as m2", function($join) {
            $join->on('m2.tid', '=', 'm1.tid');
            $join->on('m2.date',"=", DB::raw("SELECT min(m3.date) FROM tblticketreplies m3 WHERE m3.date > m1.date and m3.tid=m1.tid"));
        })
        ->select(
            'tt.id as id', 
            DB::raw('tt.date as first'),
            DB::raw('m1.date as second'),
            DB::raw('m2.date as third'),
            DB::raw('m1.userid as fid'),
            DB::raw('m2.userid as sid')
        )
        ->get();
```

Comment: No still the problem going on , not worked . I checked double orj. mysql is working well
PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'SELECT min(m3.date) FROM tblticketreplies m3 WHERE m3.date > m1.date and m3.tid=' at line 1 in /home/demospd/public_html/vendor/illuminate/database/Connection.php:333